# Webscrape using Python and BeautifulSoup - Error saving to csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to write a script that will scrape the Name, Role, and Phone numbers of real estate agents from this [website](https://www.raywhite.com/contact/?type=People&target=people&suburb=Sydney%2C%20NSW%202000&radius=10&firstname=&lastname=&_so=contact).

My code:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"card horizontal-split vcard"})

filename = "agents.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "name, role, number\n" 

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    agent_name = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-name"})
    if agent_name:
        name = agent_name[0].text

    agent_role = container.findAll("li", {"class":"agent-role"})
    if agent_role:
        role = agent_role[0].text

    filterfn = lambda x: 'href' in x.attrs and x['href'].startswith("tel")
    phones = list(map(lambda x: x.text,filter(filterfn,container.findAll("a"))))

    print("name: " + name)
    print("role: " + role)
    print("phones:" + repr(phones))

    f.write(name + "," +role + "," + phones.replace(",", "|") + "," + "\n")

f.close()
```

My code worked within the terminal before attempting to save it to a csv file that I can open in excel. However, now I'm receiving the two error messages:

```
TypeError: must be str, not list
f.write(name + "," +role + "," + phones.replace(",", "|") + "," + "\n")
```

and

```
f.write(name + "," +role + "," + phones.replace(",", "|") + "," + "\n")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

**Note, I am replacing "," with "|" to avoid creating extra columns inside the csv file.*

Comment: easiest fix for string etc. problems is pythons super simple but genius `str(yourVariable)`. This is not the answer you are looking for but a quick problem solver ;)

Comment: phones is a list, and a list does not have a replace method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error mentions, `phones` is a list that doesn't have `replace()` method. You can use `.join()` instead to join the elements of the list with the specified separator (in this case `|`):

```
f.write(name + "," +role + "," + '|'.join(phones) + "," + "\n")
```

for example:

```
>>> phones = ['123', '321', '123']
>>> '|'.join(phones)
'123|321|123'
```